# Understanding positive and negative shear strength sign

Tags: forces, structural-beam

Shear strength is a force that tries to keep stuff in equilibrium, when another force tries to break/bend/modify a structure.

This "another force" (external force) may also produce a moment.

In the following example, the moment is smoothly distributed along the structure. One can understand it, the farther from the fixed points, the easier it's to bend the structure, so... the bigger the moment.

And since we continuously walk away from the fixed points, every section continuously increases the moment it experiences, being its representation a smooth curve:

[image: diagrama]

But, I don't understand why the shear strength has a positive and a negative sign.

The whole structure is being pushed downwards... so, the internal strength should push back upwards. And not only with the same sign, but also with the same intensity.

The fact that it makes a line with zero value in the center could be seen as every piece of structure trying to hold on to the next one. So, the first one (in the middle) is the one doing nothing.

Can anybody please explain how the shear strength really works and why it's changing signs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The internal strength should push back upwards" is wrong. If you cut the beam at any point, to hold it in position you need *equal and opposite* forces on the two sides of the cut, one upwards, the other downwards.

Suppose your beam is length $l$. Measure all the forces as positive *downwards*.

The total downward load is $ql$ so the reaction force acting on the beam is $-ql/2$ at each end. Note, we are interested in *the force on the beam,* not the equal and opposite force on the support. The force the beam applies to the support is downwards, but the force the support applies to the beam is upwards.

Now suppose you cut the beam 1/4 of the way along it. On the left hand side, you have the reaction force of $-ql/2$, and a distributed load of $+ql/4$. So the shear force acting on the left side is $+ql/4$, to balance the vertical force on left hand piece of the beam.

On the right hand side, you have the reaction force $-ql/2$, but the distributed load is $+3ql/4$. So the shear force acting on the right side is $-ql/4$ to balance the vertical forces.

In other words, the shear force is $ql/4$ *downwards* on the left hand side of the cut, and $ql/2$ *upwards* on the right hand side.

Looking at it another way, the distributed load $3ql/4$ down on the right hand part of the beam is bigger than the reaction force $ql/2$ at the right hand end, so there is a net force of $ql/4$ that must be pushing down on "something," other wise the beam would move down. It is actually pushing down *on the left hand part of the beam* as the shear force in the material. And the left hand part is pushing *up* on the right hand part, with an equal and opposite force.

When you draw a shear force diagram, you show the force on one side of the imaginary cut - usually the left side if you are measuring the position along the beam from $x=0$ at the left hand end to $x=l$ at the right hand end.

If you think about what is happening at the mirror image position $x = 3l/4$, the shear forces are the mirror image of those at $x = l/4$, i.e. the shear force is down on the right hand part and up on the left hand part. Since the shear force diagram only shows the left hand force, the diagram is a mirror image about the middle of the beam - positive in the left half, negative in the right half, and zero at the mid point.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the diagram is of shear force not shear strength. The latter is the structure’s capability to resist shear stress.

The sign of the shear force is based on convention. Taking a section of beam, by convention positive shear causes a clockwise rotation of the section, that is, the shear force on the left side acts upward and on the right side acts downward of equal magnitude for force equilibrium. See the diagrams below for positive shear and bending moment.

The convention could just as well have been reversed in which case the shear diagram would be the mirror image (negative on the left positive on the right). Clearly, changing the convention has no effect on the nature of the forces in the beam. In the diagrams below we could just as well referred to the shear force on the left side of the beam as being negative and right side as positive. The direction of the forces and the effects of the shear (shear strain) remain unchanged.

Similarly positive bending moment by convention causes concave upward bending (smile). It could just as well be called negative bending in which case the bending moment diagram would show bending moment as negative. The beam will bend concave upward regardless of the convention chosen.

Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: Helps a lot, as well as the other answer. Thank you very much Bob.